# Cannot create Native Project ( C++ ) project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am using **AndroidStudio 2.1.3** I am new to native development using AndroidStudio

I followed [Creating Hello-JNI with AndroidStudio](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) .

I completed all the steps, **but** I am not getting any suggestions from AndroidStudio for generation classes in **jni folder**

I thing I missed out some setup in AndroidStudio

Following are the steps done

1. Installed `ndk-bundle`
   [image]

Following the are options that I am **not getting** in AndroidStudio

1. Android SDK (I am supposed to get this option here)

[image]

2. LLDB, CMake, and NDK, (I was supped to get options like [getting started with ndk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html))

[image]

3. create function option is missing in suggestion
   [image]

Comment: I am having the same issue! Would be awesome if more walkthrough tutorials were made available.

Comment: @Mr. Supasheva : I sorted out this problem by upgrading my AndroidStudio to 2.2.2